# Return Meta Tag as String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

I am trying to return this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So when the mobile page is displayed you will see that tag on the page.

How do I return a tag and the contents of the tag?

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly you want ?  I mean from where you are returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the `meta` element and put a clone of it in a memory `div`, and then take the `html` of that, to finally display that as text somewhere in your document:

```js
$('#output').text($('<div>').append($('meta[name=viewport]').clone()).html());
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

#### Alternative based on outerHTML

This is more straightforward: take the outer HTML of the `meta` tag and output it:

```js
$('#output').text($('meta[name=viewport]').prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are still just tags.  Treat them like you would any other type of tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('meta').each(function() {
        $('#foo').append($(this).attr('name')+": "+$(this).attr('content')+"<br />");
    });
});
```

```html
<head><title>foo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo"></div>
</body>
```